# How to make my jlabel with icon look like desktop icon?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`, now i want to make them look quite like a desktop icon i.e. icon at top and text at the bottom. This is my code, but i am getting them side by side

```
JLabel l=new JLabel("My Documents");
l.setIcon(new ImageIcon("mydocuments.png"));
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it,

```
JLabel l=new JLabel("My Documents");
l.setIcon(new ImageIcon("mydocuments.png"));

l.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
l.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
l.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
            {
                if(me.getClickCount()==2)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\My Documents"));
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: could you write the full code? I even want it's functionality.

Comment: When i double click on the icon, i should be able to open the my documents

Answer (score 2):

Try using the constructor `public JLabel(String text, Icon icon,  int horizontalAlignment)` where `horizontalAlignment` can be either one of these constants in `SwingConstants`: `LEFT`, `CENTER`, `RIGHT`, `LEADING` or `TRAILING`.

You can view the full Javadoc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel(java.lang.String, javax.swing.Icon, int)

Comment: That is just horizontal alignment! It does not bring the text to the bottom!! anyways it doesn't seem to make a change to the text position